# Assign exit status and arguments with shell script (unix)

Tags: shell, unix, sh

For all the files (in the current directory) that contain the WORD that is the 1st command line argument, I have to insert the second command line argument on a new line at the head of the file.Then I have to Print usage and exit with status 4 if not given two args. Exit status 1 is there were there are no such files. Exit status 2 if any of the files could not be altered. Exit status 0 otherwise.

For Example:

> Suppose the script filename is **addwarn.sh** then,
>
> ```
> echo "I am a string" > f1
> echo "I am not a string > f2
> ./addwarn.sh "not" '*** WARNING ***'
> cat f1 f2
>
> I am a string
> *** WARNING ***
> I am not a string
> ```

What I have tried so far:

```
#! bin/sh

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    exit

fi

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    cat *
fi
```

I am not sure how to make a script, any ideas?

Comment: Why are you trying to check `$?` in your script?

Comment: I was trying to get exit status

Comment: Exit status of what?

Comment: Of the last command to get zero value, but it seems pretty much wrong.

Comment: What last command? What does any of this have to do with the task described in your first paragraph?

Comment: exit status variable is always for the previous command you have run. Calling a script that checks `$?` is "too late". Checking `$?` is alway right next to the cmd, like `/bin/ls -l myFiles* ; echo "rc=$?"` , or most basically, `true; echo $? ; false ; echo $? ; nonesuch ; echo $?`. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Looks like a nice homework problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
found=0

usage(){
    echo "$0 takes two args!"
    exit 4
} 

#check for two args
i=0
for a in "$@"; do
    ((i++))
done
[ "$i" -ne "2" ] && usage

uneditable=0
for f in $(find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f); do
    if grep -q $1 $f ; then
        found=1
        echo -e "$2\n$(cat $f)" > $f || uneditable=1
    fi
done
[ "$found" = "0" ] && exit 1
[ "$uneditable" = "1" ] && exit 2
exit 0
```